# Use of zoopkeeper.znode.parent properties in hbase?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

Can you anyone explain

1.Use of zoopkeeper.znode.parent properties in hbase

2.How to set spark class path for hbase in secure cluster(kerbose)

3.Apart from hbase class path what are the other required file or path need to be place in spark classpath.while we use spark submit in HDP

Thanks!